# can i connect a Floppy Drive to USB Adapter / copy data, can i emulate a floppy drive and rip?

Tags: usb, ms-dos, data-transfer, floppy

can i connect a 1.44MB 3.5" Floppy Drive Connector 34 PIN 34P to USB Adapter to somethign and copy the data, *(rather than connecting a floppy drive and copying to floopy and then transferign it via floppy to another pc?) ie can i emulate a floppy drive and rip?

its an old network device and some one wants to reverce engeneer soem of the GUI, has a ps2 kyb header and can get to post, running dos6, it can output to floppy with on board floppy headers, *(that i need to solder in)

i want to know if i can use a floppy to usb adapter, and emulate a floppy drive to save data,   like if i could only use a floppy to usb connector, and attach a female to female usb adapter to a flashdrive, lol ,

but if there was a way i coudl conenct this to windows or a linux distro and "emulate" the floppy drive to save the file and transfer it i would be golden,

*(idk why they want the old emdedded os and structure of an old network tester, but thats the request i got lol )

thank you

something like this

[floppy to usb](https://www.ebay.com/i/283228590717?chn=ps&norover=1&mkevt=1&mkrid=711-117182-37290-0&mkcid=2&itemid=283228590717&targetid=934793862936&device=c&mktype=pla&googleloc=9032536&poi=&campaignid=10880341817&mkgroupid=110621917401&rlsatarget=pla-934793862936&abcId=9300400&merchantid=114733925&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI0Pvysr_D7AIVRIJbCh2yqwIAEAQYAiABEgJKOPD_BwE)

applying to a device like this

[network tester hack](https://tinkerfiddle.blogspot.com/2017/11/hacking-on-digital-lightwave-asa-pkg_25.html?m=1)

Comment: If its DOS it has a FAT file system.  If the hard drive/storage is IDE your better off getting a USB to IDE is better choice.

Answer (score 0):

Sweet.  That helps
I feel i might go that route if i can.

If i could bypass the floppy drive part and just import data as floppy over the USB. *(onboard floppy headders to usb and pull it off straght to a file would be perfect.  Incase whats on there is more than one floppys size.

Thankyou.   I migt try this and see what i get

Answer (score -1):

Sometime ago I bought a floppy drive with a USB connector on it at a local Walmart. It connects fine to an open USB adapter. The computer recognizes it as a floppy drive whether I'm running Windows or Linux and I can either copy or read files from a floppy disk mounted in the drive.